# ASP.NET MVC StackTrace still shown even when disabling in HttpConfiguration and web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, error-handling, stack-trace

When an error is produced in my production website, stack trace info is being sent over. I do not want to include this information.

Based on my research into this issue I have configured my HttpConfiguration (via the WebApiConfigurationBroadcaster) to have:

```
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Never;
```

And my web.config file is like so:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultResponseMode="File">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="500.html" responseMode="File" />
</httpErrors>
```

Yet, still a stack trace is shown, even after restarting the server. I'm trying to figure out how this is being bypassed. I'm a maintainer of this code.

**Version Information**: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3535.0

Answer (score 0):

Change the `trace enabled` to `false` in your `web.config`

```
<configuration>

<system.web>

<trace enabled="false" localOnly="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set as below:

```
<trace enabled="flase" localOnly="true"/>
```

by using code:

```
#If DEBUG Then
  CType(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page).Trace.Write("Test - Cache       
 hit")
#End If
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/6915t83k(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN